# Storing Images in Azure and Accessing it in Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Before I published the website I've been working on to Azure, I kept all the images inside a local "Catalog" folder which was referenced in the program like;

> image src='/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ImagePath%

Now it is deployed on Azure, I believe I need to turn to something called "Unstructured Blob Storage" to store and retrieve the images on the website.

This is my first time using Azure, I am wondering if it is as easy as storing the images in an unstructured blob storage on Azure, then just changing the "Catalog/Images/Thumbs" to the file path on Azure.

Does anybody know exactly how this works?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the Azure Blob Storage [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs)? They also have a bunch of code samples.

Comment: it would need to be an absolute URL, rather than a file path I would guess, since the files will no longer be stored on the same server/domain, e.g. https://storagesample.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/photos/myphoto.jpg as per the docs linked in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, after deployed your web application to Azure, you could still store your resources (e.g. image, doc, excel, etc.) within your web application. In order to better manage your resources and reduce the pressure for your application when serving the static resources, you could store your resources in a central data store.

> This is my first time using Azure, I am wondering if it is as easy as storing the images in an unstructured blob storage on Azure, then just changing the "Catalog/Images/Thumbs" to the file path on Azure.

Based on your requirement, you could create a blob container named `catalog` and upload your images to the virtual directory `Images/Thumbs`, and set anonymous read access to your container and blobs. For a simple way, you could leverage [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) to upload your images and set access level for your container as follows:

[image]

[image]

And you `image` would look like this:

```
<img src="https://brucchstorage.blob.core.windows.net/catalog/Images/Thumbs/lake.jpeg">
```

Moreover, you could leverage [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2ffiles%2ftoc.json) to copy data to Azure Blob storage using simple commands with optimal performance. Additionally, you could leverage Azure Storage client library to manage your storage resources, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs).